# Different calculations results in in SQL (using JOIN / WHERE / GROUP) and Google Sheets SUMIF/AVERAGEIF for the same dataset

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

Use the same data for SQL & Google Sheets calculations but can't understand why in SQL and Google Sheets I have different values for the total.
2 use cases are described below

---

1. **I have 2 tables:**
2. 1st table data columns: ordernumber, sales number, status, month_id, dealsize
3. 2nd table data columns: ordernumber, year_id, productline, city, country, territory
4. **The task is:** to find out the number of motorcycle sales (Productline = ‘Motorcycles’) in 2003 by region (Territory)

I wrote such a request and got the answer

```
SELECT 
year_country.year_id year,
year_country.territory territory,
year_country.productline product,
sum(sales_size.sales) total_sales

FROM sales_size
JOIN year_country
ON sales_size.ordernumber = year_country.ordernumber
WHERE year_country.productline = "Motorcycles" AND year_id = "2003"
GROUP by year_country.territory
;
```

[image]

But when I re-checked the calculations just in Google Sheets I found out that the total is wrong. In Google Sheets, I just put the content of both table into one and then used SUMIF formula.

```
=sumifs([range],[range],"Motorcycles",[range],"NA",[range],"2003")
```

- APAC = 12058.72
- EMEA = 50956.2
- NA = 65887.91

---

1. Then the same 2 tables
2. **The task is:** to find the average cost of the order (SALES) by year

I wrote such a request and got the answer

```
SELECT 
year_country.year_id year,
round(avg(sales_size.sales)) average_sales

FROM sales_size
JOIN year_country
ON sales_size.ordernumber = year_country.ordernumber
GROUP by year_id
;
```

[image]

But when I re-checked the calculations just in Google Sheets I found out that the average is also wrong. In Google Sheets, I just put the content of both table into one and then used AVERAGEIF formula.

```
=AVERAGEIF([range],[year],[range])
```

- 2003 = 5454
- 2004 = 5298
- 2005 = 4958

---

Source tables

- [1st table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CBEBFkHFXUVTCUJxRo4jXGotlyK0DFiMhp2rxMyw928/edit?usp=sharing)
- [2nd table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L5l2nqPGgPps56ZF7xAJiLqNyP0HTBnjl7rYn27A7KE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please don’t link to, or use, images. Add all information directly to your question preferably as editable text

Comment: As I mentioned in your previous question, it makes no sense to include columns like `year_id` and `product` in the result, since there are lots of different values of those columns in each territory.

Comment: Without seeing how you're doing the sums in Google Sheets, it's hard to explain why the results are different.

Comment: There are 3 rows for `ordernumber = 10107` in each table. You're getting a cross product of them before you sum, so it multiplies the sum by 3.

Comment: @Barmar I've just put these 2 tables inside one and used AVERAGEIF/SUMIF to recheck values
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tPJC0rrBMlNQ6Y7qC87eOBRsDP3wuyGYz7cTAh0ewvw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @NickW unfortunately, you can't share code in sqliteonline

Comment: @VelGreen Combining into a single table is not at all like joining.